# stopPropagation and preventDefault don't work with select2 for remove tags button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to prevent click propagation on the following element:

```
.select2-selection__choice__remove
```

I try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("document").on(
    "mouseup",
    ".select2-selection__choice__remove",
    function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    },
  );
});
```

The example I want to solve is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/dk_dragonknight/c1ef7138/

I need that, when clicking on the "x" icon on the left side of the tag, the dropdown does not close (stopPropagation needs to work for this).

Note: this is just a code I posted to reproduce the problem, it's not mine and therefore I need a solution for this here

Comment: Your `$("document").on("mouseup", ".select2-selection__choice__remove",` isn't even firing when added to that fiddle, so there's nothing to "cancel".   Need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - A doesn't work, so I'll try to fix it with B - B also doesn't work, so I'll ask a question on how to get B to work instead of how to get A to work.  Relatively simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need that, when clicking on the "x" icon on the left side of the tag, the [outer] dropdown [not select2] does not close

Looking at your provided fiddle, you already have a check not to close the outer dropdown in certain situations; you just need to add the select2-close button to that check:

```
!$(e.target).hasClass("select2-selection__choice__remove")
```

Updated snippet from the fiddle:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown .cycle-element', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$('.dropdown').is(e.target) 
      && $('.dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0 
      && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0 
      && !$(e.target).hasClass("select2-selection__choice__remove")) {
    $('.dependency-select').select2('close');
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');

  }
});

$('.dependency-select').select2();
```

```css
.cycle-element {
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown" data-type="video">
    <div class="cycle-element">
      Click Me <span class="content-number"></span>
      <div class="pull-right hide"><span class="caret"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <h3>
        Settings
      </h3>
      <hr />
      <select name="dependency" class="form-control dependency-select" style="width: 100%" multiple>
        <option>Test 1</option>
        <option>Test 2</option>
        <option>Test 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop events propagating from an element that you need to bind your event listener to **that** element.

You are currently using event delegation. You’ve bound the event listener to the document and are testing to see if it propagated from the select to the document before calling your function.

By the time you call stopPropagation, the event has propagated almost as far as it was going to anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `mouseup` event just use `click` event on the parent container then apply the `stopPropagation` here, That prevents event bubbling upwards the `document` element so eventually select2 won't close on `x` icon click.

[Bubbling-and-capturing DOC](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

I have tested in your fiddle.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(e=>{
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: The issue isn't select2 closing, it's OP's `$("body").click(..close outer popdown..)`